# code to check logged in user has both roles in tpl file?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, roles, drupal-modules

I want to print in a page--node--17.tpl.php a code to check for roles from the logged in user and then determine what should be shown, so basically a user must have BOTH roles A and C and if they do i print xxx
If they have roles A and B i write yyy
if they have roles B and C i print zzz

So the code below can check for one role, but how do i do both.. its important that BOTH roles need to be there, a user with just one of the roles will not qualify.

thank u

```
<?php
  global $user;
  // Check to see if $user has the administrator user role.
  if (in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) {
    // Do something.
  }
?>
```

also i have this code but i think this is only checking one of the roles, so it checks for either A or B

```
<?php
global $user;
$check = array_intersect(array('moderator', 'administrator'), array_values($user->roles));
    if (empty($check) ? FALSE : TRUE) {
    // is admin
    } else {
    // is not admin
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a reusable function

```
<?php
function _mytheme_check_for_all_roles_present($roles) {
  global $user;      
  foreach($roles as $key => $role) {
    if (in_array($role, array_values($user->roles))) {
      unset($roles[$key]);
    }
  }

  return empty($roles);
}
```

Use it to check if the user has the roles.

```
<?php 

$roles = array('role_1_to_be_checked', 'role_2_to_be_checked');

if(_mytheme_check_for_all_roles_present($roles) {
  echo "the thing you want to show";
}
```

you can also do,

```
<?php


if(_mytheme_check_for_all_roles_present(array('role_1_to_be_checked', 'role_2_to_be_checked')) {
  echo "the thing you want to show";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to check if two conditions are true, you need an AND (&&) operator.

In your exemple I would do this:

```
<?php
//Load the current user
global $user;

// Check to see if $user has the A, B or C user role.
$as_A_role = in_array('A', array_values($user->roles));
$as_B_role = in_array('B', array_values($user->roles));
$as_C_role = in_array('C', array_values($user->roles));
?>

<?php if ($as_A_role && $as_B_role): ?>

  // Do something.

<?php elseif ($as_A_role && $as_C_role): ?>

  // Do something else

<?php endif; ?>
```